# nohup in alias has problem "nohup: missing operand"

Tags: command-line, bash, alias, nohup

Hi I was trying to create an alias to run a shell script in background:
`alias inj=nohup ~/software/idea-IU/bin/idea.sh` in my `~/.bashrc`
But as I type `inj` in terminal, I got `nohup: missing operand` error.
I verified that it works fine if I directly call `nohup ~/software/idea-IU/bin/idea.sh` in terminal but it just doesn't work when it's in alias.
So is there some other tricks that I'm not aware of that's causing this?

Comment: Pass it as single string - so quote it: `alias inj='nohup ~/software/idea-IU/bin/idea.sh'`

Comment: imo, your example should be a function, not an alias, `inj(){ nohup ~/software/idea-IU/bin/idea.sh; }`. With an alias you can add arguments, but you don't seem to need that here.